# In a collection of objects, how do i extract one attribute from each to new list?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have an `IQueryable<MyType>`. MyType has ID, Value and TypeId properties.

How can I use a Lambda expression to place all the TypeId properties into a new List?

Comment: `queryable.Select(o => o.TypeId).ToList()`. That's pretty basic, so you should brush up your LINQ a bit.

Comment: @Jon: You are definitely right. I'm very rusty on this, as we are mostly fixing old code at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newList = source.Select(item=>item.TypeId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
IQueryable<MyType> source;

var result = source.Select(s => s.TypeId>).ToList();
```

this will result in a `List<string>` if TypeId is of Type string

Comment: Awesome, thanks! @Justin Beat you by 2 seconds! I'll try to find another answer of yours that helped me, to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Try following lambda expression . It will return a new list with `TypeId` type.

```
IQueryable<MyType> list;
var newList = list.Select(item=>item.TypeId).ToList();
```